# Communicate between two socket server

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, p2p

I have two TCP socket server in python, each with some (about 4) clients. I want the two server to be able to talk to each other so both can send commands to each other and communicate.

Is this possible? And if yes, how?

Comment: yes of course you have just to make one of them client of the other

Comment: I don't know what you really mean, but he will continue to serve his clients as well

Comment: I'm a bit confused right now, sorry, I'm new in programming. So how can I make a computer act like a client and as a server? Even if I try to use the same port it gives me an error...

Comment: okay, I will post a complete answer with a brief example on how you can do that

Comment: take a look at zeromq, all the network stuff will be abstracted from you and you can focus on your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example:

```
import socket
socket_between_servers = None


def connect_to(host='', port=1060):
   global socket_between_servers
   sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   try:
      sock.connect((host, port))  #check if the first server is already waiting
      socket_between_servers = sock
   except socket.error:
      s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
      s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
      s.bind((host, port))
      s.listen(5)  # waiting for the 4 clients plus the other server
      print 'waiting for the peers...'
      n = 0
      while n < 5:
         sc, sockname = s.accept()
         if sockname == 'ip addresse of the other server':
            socket_between_servers = sc
         n += 1
   else:
      s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
      s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
      s.bind((host, port + 1))
      s.listen(4)  # waiting for the 4 clients
      n = 0
      while n < 4:
         sc, sockname = s.accept()
```

then with `socket_between_servers` the servers can communicate

Comment: thanks! i understand the concept now and will try to implement that